# Library Member class, can't figure out where I'm going wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to complete a series of class definition tasks and can't seem to get past this one. It is part of a 3 part series; the first part asks you to model a library book, which I could complete easily.

The next part is asking to create a `Member` class to model a library member and include a `borrow_book()` and a `return_book()` method, and to get the member's list of all loan books to print out in alphabetical order.

I cannot understand which part I am going wrong on. Could someone possibly point me in the right direction? I have included my code so far below.

```
class Book(object):

    def __init__(self, title, author, copies=1, loan=0):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.copies = copies
        self.loan = loan

    def checkbook(self, title):
        for book in self.title:
            if book.title in self.title:
                return book
            else:
                print("Sorry, Not Available.")

    def  borrow_book(self):
        abc = self.checkbook(title)
        print(abc)
        self.loan += 1
        self.copies -= 1

    def return_book(self):
        self.loan -= 1

    def __str__(self):
        r = []
        r.append('Title: {}'.format(self.title))
        r.append('Author: {}'.format(self.author))
        r.append('Copies: {}'.format(self.copies))
        r.append('On loan: {}'.format(self.loan))
        return '\n'.join(r)

def sort_books(b):
    return b.title

class Member(object):

    def __init__(self, mid, name, loans=0):
        self.mid = mid
        self.name = name
        self.loans = loans
        self.d = {}

    def __str__(self, mid, name, loans=0):
        r = []
        r.append('ID: {}'.format(self.mid))
        r.append('Name: {}'.format(self.name))
        r.append('Loans: {}'.format(self.loans))
        l = ['{}'.format(b) for b in sorted(self.d.values(), key=sort_books)]
        return '\n'.join(r)
        return '\n'.join(l)
```

Comment: `borrow_book` and `return_book` should be in the `Member` class, not the `Book` class.

Comment: `Book` should only track the title and author. The number of copies is not a property of the book, but of the collection that *holds* the book. A `Library` class, for instance, might maintain a dict like `{Book("Moby Dick", "Melville"): (2, 1), ...}` which indicates that the library has two copies of *Moby Dick*, one of which is currently checked out.

Comment: How are you "going wrong"? What is your question exactly?